# TextMeasurer gives different line end than the actual Text in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'm trying to count the number of characters displayed by a Text without rendering it. I thought I could use a TextMeasurer, however the number of "measured" characters is different than the number of characters I get if I render the actual Text.

This is the code I'm using:

```
val text= "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor " +
        "incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. " +
        "Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor. Accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus " +
        "iaculis urna id."
val textStyle = TextStyle(
    hyphens = Hyphens.Auto,
    lineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph
)
val maxLines = 2
BoxWithConstraints {
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val measuredLayoutResult = textMeasurer.measure(
        text = text,
        style = textStyle,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        constraints = constraints,
    )
    val measuredCharacters = measuredLayoutResult.getLineEnd(measuredLayoutResult.lineCount - 1)
    println("Measured characters : ${measuredCharacters}")
    Text(
        text,
        style = textStyle,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
        onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
            val actualCharacters = textLayoutResult.getLineEnd(textLayoutResult.lineCount - 1)
            println("Actual characters : ${actualCharacters}")
        },
    )
}
```

I'm getting two different numbers:

- Measured characters : 124
- Actual characters : 128

Removing the textAlign makes the numbers equal. However that's not an option for me and I don't see a way to give the textAlign param to the measure function. Is there a way to do so?